# RazorEngine: Does not parse variable that appears after a less than sign ("<")

Tags: c#, razor, razorengine

When a razor template has a variable wrapped in parenthesis (ex. "(@Model.B)" in the code below), the razor engine fails to compile and replace that variable if it is preceded by a "<" and separated by space or text. Is this intended behavior? If the variable is not wrapped in parenthesis then the template is parsed just fine.

```
[Test]
public void TestWeirdLangleBracketError()
{
    var template = "(@Model.B)";
    var model = new Model { B = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() };
    var templateService =
        new TemplateService(new TemplateServiceConfiguration { EncodedStringFactory = new RawStringFactory() });

    //It is replaced here
    //Result of Try1: "(f9e0f220-0df8-4942-9d84-e403c622af96)"
    templateService.Compile(template, typeof(Model), "Try1");
    Assert.True(templateService.Run("Try1", model, null).Contains(model.B));
    //But not here
    //Result of Try2: " < (@Model.B)"
    templateService.Compile(" < " + template, typeof(Model), "Try2");
    Assert.False(templateService.Run("Try2", model, null).Contains(model.B));
}

public class Model
{
    public string B { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: is there an error message?

Comment: The code compiles and executes without error albeit with unexpected results.

Answer (score 1):

Razor heavily relies on the < > signs to find tags which it will use as html.

To solve your issue you can use the xml replacement for <

```
&lt; (@Model.B)
```

the actual code is getting replaced in the answer look up less than sign xml encoded for the actual replacement text

or this

```
@("<") (@Model)
```

it is the < that is the issue not your `Model.B` definition.

Comment: Both should technically work. If the @ is outside the parenthesis than the razor should evaluate the parenthesis as part of the expression. If it is inside than it should not include them in the expression evaluation and output them as raw text, which is why the resulting string has the GUID in parenthesis.

Comment: Edited my answer to be more aligned with your issue

Answer (score -1):

There is an error in your line of code.

```
templateService.Compile(" < " + template, typeof(Model), "Try2");
```

I has no reference to @Model.B, so it will output only " < "

You need to actually include the variable, like this.

```
templateService.Compile(" < (@Model.B)" + template, typeof(Model), "Try2");
```

Comment: var template = "(@Model.B)";
So @Model.B is referenced there.